# Calling function in child passed from parent in useEffect() hook, React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, use-effect

I have defined a function in my parent component that updates local state and passed it to the child component. In the child component I want to call the function in useEffect hook every time the magLockDropdown dependency value changes. When trying to do this I get a lint warning shown below. Would it be a good idea to disable the linter for this example? I understand every time the parent re renders it re creates the function that is being passed down but not sure if this is causing the warning. Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Function in parent component.

```
const updateWeeklyTestState = (name, value) => {
setWeeklyTest({
  ...weeklyTest, [name]: value
})}
```

UseState hook in child component.

```
  useEffect(() => {
  updateWeeklyTestState (failList, maglockDropdown)
  }, [maglockDropdown])
```

esLint Warning:

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'updateWeeklyTestState '. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

**EDIT**

Child Declaration

```
export default function Maglocks (props) {
const [maglockDropdown, setMaglockDropdown] = useState(['Pass'])
const { maglocks, weeklyTestState, updateWeeklyTestState, addFailedMaglocksToArray } = props
```

Comment: Can you paste the child component's declaration? i.e. the part where you name the component

Comment: Sure! I have edited my post.

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't clear if updateWeeklyTestState was being properly pulled out of props, but it looks like you have that down.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   useEffect(() => {
        if(updateWeeklyTestState){
           updateWeeklyTestState (failList, maglockDropdown)
        }
   }, [maglockDropdown])
```

or this

```
  export default function Maglocks (props) {
  const { maglocks, weeklyTestState, updateWeeklyTestState, addFailedMaglocksToArray } = props
  const [maglockDropdown, setMaglockDropdown] = useState(['Pass'])
```

Answer (score 0):

by now(without anything async in your `useEffect`) it's safe to ignore warning. Otherwise if `setWeeklyTest` is not coming from `useState` or `useCallback` you may face "stale data issue"(so it will be called with wrong/out-of-date input data).

On the other side, if you just put `updateWeeklyTestState` into `useEffect`'s dependency, you will get body running each time parent re-renders(that could be against your needs).

So I propose also declare `updateWeeklyTestState` as `useCallback` so it would be referentially the same:

```
const updateWeeklyTestState = useCallback((name, value) => {
setWeeklyTest({
  ...weeklyTest, [name]: value
})}, [setWeeklyTest]);
```

and then adding as a dependency to `useEffect` will not break your logic:

```
useEffect(() => {
  updateWeeklyTestState (failList, maglockDropdown)
}, [maglockDropdown, updateWeeklyTestState])
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simply `linting` warning as you said.

Here,

```
useEffect(() => {
  updateWeeklyTestState (failList, maglockDropdown)
  }, [maglockDropdown])
```

the hook depend on `updateWeeklyTestState`.So,it need to passed to hooks as a dependancy list.

**`Because of missing dependancy linting giving this warning.`**

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment, unfortunately adding the prop to the dependency list causes  an infinite loop because there is form fields on the child component that are controlled by the parent component, which causes a parent re render and a new updateWeeklyTestState reference being created each time.

Comment: @GaB pass `updateWeeklyTestState` using useCallback hooks